# Running a command with ActiveX only tries to create a file named my command

Tags: vbscript, cmd, command, registry, activex

I run this vbscript on an html page

```
Dim WinScriptHost
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v name_of_key /d C:\path\to\exe /f" & Chr(34), 0
```

And it's not working. I look in Procmon and see that it ran a `create file` command to the path `C:\root\directory\of\html\file\reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v name_of_key /d C:\path\to\exe /`

Why would it try to create a file? Why isn't it just running it?

(I think the real command should have a `cmd /C` prepended, but the same problem occurs. It tries creating a file, just with `cmd /C` prepended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by taking away the `Char(24)`'s

the new code is:

```
WinScriptHost
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WinScriptHost.Run "reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v name_of_key /d C:\path\to\exe /f", 0
```